# Using jZMQ binding with Java SDK 6 instead of 7

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, jmonkeyengine, jzmq

I'm trying to get ZeroMQ http://www.zeromq.org/ running with the following configuration / requirements:

- OS X 10.8 with built in Java SDK 7
- Java binding for ZMQ
- Need to use SDK 6

Apparently jzmq was compiled with the header files of Java SDK 7, but I really need to have them compiled with the header files of SDK 6. That's because I want to use http://jmonkeyengine.org/ which currently supports only SDK 6.

So my general question is, how to get this working or maybe just a hint where to obtain the SDK 6 header files and how to compile jzmq with them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one the maintainers of the JZMQ ZeroMQ binding.

I would post an issue here: https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/issues?state=open and I'll be sure to cut a new release soon that is built with Java6.

Comment: The last couple tagged builds of JZMQ were built with Java6